# Opening a bag file with rqt_bag from the command line?

Tags: ros, rqt-bag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With rxbag I could do "rxbag bagfile". How do I do the same with rqt_bag? It is very inconvenient to use open and the graphical file browser to open a bag file.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51656/opening-a-bag-file-with-rqt_bag-from-the-command-line?/) by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1339 on 2013-01-08

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently it is not possible but it is trivial to implement. I filled a feature request at https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/issues/10 - it should be available in the next patch release of rqt_bag.

Update: the changes have been committed to rqt_common_plugins and will be available with the next version 0.2.8.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3